# Argument completion for python

Tags: autocompletion, ide, filetype-python

Is there a way to get argument completion for python?

I am currently using a combination of ctags, python-mode and YouCompleteMe, but I am missing a function to autocomplete the arguments of a function (or show them at least.)

Is there a Plugin that supports that?

I am using vim/gvim 7.4 and Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, (with a minimal vimrc, and no plugins installed), this is already possible.

Vim ships with multiple filetype plugins and some of these plugins offer omni-completion right out of the box. For example, python comes with pythoncomplete.vim.

If you use the default pythoncomplete.vim that ships with Vim, (i.e. no YouCompleteMe, no python-mode, no jedi-vim), you get a preview window when you complete a function, that shows the keyword arguments.

All you need is Vim with `+python` feature (`:echo has('python')` shows 1). If you do, then this is all it takes to enable the default python omni-completion with your vimrc:

`filetype plugin indent on`

After hunting down many other completion solutions for python (jedi, python-mode), I've come to like pythoncomplete.vim that is shipped with Vim a lot more. It's simple, and most important to me, it's very stable, especially compared to solutions like jedi-vim/python-mode and YouCompleteMe.

This is what the default solution looks like. It doesn't offer completion of arguments, but just shows them in the preview window so it's easy for you to fill the keyword arguments in like so:

[image]

Comment: @lcd047: In what way does this not answer the question? The question was to find a solution to "autocomplete the arguments of a function (or show them at least.)". I suggested a solution that would show the arguments of a function. You proposed the completion of arguments, I proposed the showing of them. The questioner can pick his preference. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: I want to find more information on this plugin. How do you use it? Do I need ctags for it?

Comment: @NeaţuOvidiuGabriel: this plugin is built into Vim, you don't need anything other than what my answer tells you.

Comment: How do you activate the preview window? Is there a keyboard shortcut?